# Local files from Tableview to Webview Detail

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a `UITableView` whose each row must take me to a detail page containing UIWebView .At each item (row) of `Tableview` there is a local HTML file.
With this code, I support the same HTML file:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("yyy", withExtension: "html")
    let myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: localfilePath!)
    webView.loadRequest(myRequest)
}
```

How to assign to each row the HTML file that matches it?

Answer (score 0):

Make a property `selectedHTMLFileName` at this viewcontroller where you loading webview. From previous controller having tableview, handle `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and set this property to your filename.

```
let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(self.selectedHTMLFileName, withExtension: "html")
```

**EDIT:**

Something like this can work.

```
class IntroTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var labelintro = [String]()
    var webAddresses = [String]()
    int selectedIndex = 0;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    labelintro = ["Avant-propos", "Zone Sakalava", "Pronontiation", "Conjugaison", "Verbes indispensables","Grammaire & synthaxe","Mots indispensables","Les comptes","Le temps", "Termes de politesse", "La famille", "Se déplacer", "Le commerces", "Les vêtements", "Se loger", "Nourritures, épices & condiments", "Nature & paysages", "Ville, village", "L'école", "La flore", "La faune", "Santé & corps", "Artisanat, tradition & sacré", "Expressions courantes"]


    webAddresses = ["xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html"]

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
                              sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "gotodetail" {
        var detailIntroVC = segue!.destinationViewController as DetailIntroViewController;
        detailIntroVC.selectedHTMLFileName = webAddresses[selectedIndex];
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return labelintro.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("texteintrocell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! IntroTableViewCell


    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.labelIntro.text = labelintro[row]

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

 selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gotodetail", sender: self)

   }

}
```

and in DetailViewController :

```
class DetailIntroViewController: UIViewController {


string selectedHTMLFileName;
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Use filename without extension
    var fileNameComponents = split(selectedHTMLFileName) {$0 == "."}
    selectedHTMLFileName = fileNameComponents[0]

    let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(selectedHTMLFileName, withExtension: "html")

    }
}
```

This code is not tested, but you can check the flow of the process.

Changes made are:

1. `prepareForSegue` code updated
2. Added property `selectedIndex`
3. Added `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` event
4. Added property `selectedHTMLFileName` in Detail viewcontroller.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tested but it did not look as easy for me as for you ...

Comment: What have you tested, show us the code. Also, if possible please add the code that pushes this controller having webview.

Answer (score 0):

In my TableViewController :

```
    class IntroTableViewController: UITableViewController {
        var labelintro = [String]()
        var webAddresses = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        labelintro = ["Avant-propos", "Zone Sakalava", "Pronontiation", "Conjugaison", "Verbes indispensables","Grammaire & synthaxe","Mots indispensables","Les comptes","Le temps", "Termes de politesse", "La famille", "Se déplacer", "Le commerces", "Les vêtements", "Se loger", "Nourritures, épices & condiments", "Nature & paysages", "Ville, village", "L'école", "La flore", "La faune", "Santé & corps", "Artisanat, tradition & sacré", "Expressions courantes"]


        webAddresses = ["xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html","xxx.html", "yyy.html"]

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
                                  sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "gotodetail" {
            _ = segue.destinationViewController
                as! DetailIntroViewController
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return labelintro.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("texteintrocell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! IntroTableViewCell


        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.labelIntro.text = labelintro[row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

And in my DetailViewController :

```
    class DetailIntroViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(self.selectedHTMLFileName, withExtension: "html")

        }
}
```